# Photographer arranging six people in a row

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can a photographer at a wedding arrange $6$ people in a row, including the bride and the groom, if the bride should be positioned in the groom's left.

Don't have a idea to start this one.

Comment: Do you mean that the bride must be seated next to the groom and on his left, or merely that she needs to be on his left side?  That is, is $\{*,*,B,*,*,G\}$ an acceptable arrangement?

Comment: She needs to be on his left side but not necessarily close to him

Comment: Yes. This set is an acceptable arrangement.

Comment: In that case, note that we can always switch $B$ and $G$...so there are exactly as many configurations with her on the left as with her on the right.  Thus, the answer is half the total number of permutations.

Comment: @lulu nice observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the bride has to be on the left of the groom there are $5$ admissible positions for the groom (second, third, etc, sixth but not first). If the position of the groom is $k$ for $k=2,3,4,5,6$ then you can place the bride in $k-1$ positions that are on the left. This gives you $$\sum_{k=2}^{6}(k-1)=\sum_{k=1}^5k=\frac{5(5+1)}{2}=15$$ ways to place them. In each of these ways, the rest of the positions may be filled in an arbitrary way, so there are $4!$ ways to do that, which gives a total of $$15\cdot4!=360$$

---

Of course the simplest answer is mentioned in the comments: Due to symmetry there are as many ways to place the bride on the left of the groom as to place her on the right of the groom. Since the total ways are $6!$ this gives immediately that the answer is $$\frac{6!}{2}=\frac{720}{2}=360$$ thus confirming the above approach.